# Combine reports of 2 kinds. Possible?

Tags: civireport, reports, custom-reports

I would like to get a report of "activities" and include some information specifically related to contribution. This is what I am expecting to see in results the report:

- Source name - (backend user)
- Target name - (Donor name)
- Activities-(contribution only)
- Payment method- (connected to the
  activity)
- Contribution for
- Contribution Note
- Contribution Amount
- Activity date
- Activity status

Is it something possible to achieve? Thanks

Comment: Hi Tapash - how are the contributions related to the activities? Also - to help me understand - what is the difference between Activity date and status vs contribution date and status?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am trying to get a report based on contribution created by a backend user. Activity date and status vs contribution date and status are same. My main point is to get report contribution created by an ACL user Group. Only way to get report based on user entry looks like available in "Activities" report. other columns going to present a clear picture.of entire report